# What is the current state of Ubuntu on Bay Trail tablets?

Tags: tablet

I'm thinking of purchasing a Bay Trail (actually Cherry Trail) tablet. Specifically, the [Insignia Flex 8](http://www.bestbuy.ca/en-ca/product/insignia-insignia-flex-8-32gb-windows-10-tablet-with-intel-cherrytrail-z8300-quad-core-processor-black-ns-p08w7100-c/10437094.aspx).

What is the current state of Ubuntu (as of now) on these types of tablets? I see other questions but they are for older verisons of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I got mine to boot, but couldn't get the touchscreen, camera or screen rotation to work.

To get ubuntu to boot, you need to find a 32bit uefi to add to a live usb. Then boot usb from the windows recovery menu.

Comment: I was able to get mine to boot. But I can't try anymore as it broke earlier. It's a very good tablet while it lasts (6 months)
. Open a chat room with me if you'd like more details.

Comment: When you had it booting, did you experience the same issues I had?

Comment: Screen rotation worked on 17.04 I believe. However it was always off by 90 degrees. I think that problem can be fixed easily in a script. Apparently they have broken it in 17.10 from what you've said. I did not try the camera, but I know that the touchscreen was unresponsive.